# mysql infile can't access @user variable in sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to read a csv file and insert rows into a table. I am able to insert them without any problem when I am assigning the value. But the same sql  stops working when I try to use a @user variable.

All help is appreciated.

**This works:**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'tmp/test.csv'

INTO TABLE T1

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
( @var1 )
set create_timestamp = now(), 
col1 = ( select max(id) from T2 where 
col2 = 1234 );
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'tmp/test.csv'

INTO TABLE T1

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
( @var1 )
set create_timestamp = now(), 
col1 = ( select max(id) from T2 where 
col2 = @var1 );
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: The problem is happening in sub query, where it is not able to access the user variable here @var1.

the subquery works when I give it a constant value such as 1234.

Comment: @Anika . . . It is generating an error.  If so what?  Is it generated undesired results.  If so what?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the subquery **`( select max(id) from`** is being executed *before* a value is assigned to `@var1`.

I'm actually surprised that the first example works at all; I've never tried running a subquery in a `LOAD DATA`.

When you say "This doesn't work" do you mean that the LOAD DATA throws an error? Or do you mean that the `LOAD DATA` completes successfully, but with unexpected results?

In the latter case, I'd recommend a simple test, doing a separate `SET @var1 = 1234;` statement before the `LOAD DATA`, and see what happens for the first row.

If it's throwing an error, it may be that a subquery isn't supported in that context. (We'd need to consult the MySQL Reference Manual, to see if that is supported.)

That's my *guesses*. 1) unexpected order of operations (`@var1` is being evaluated *before* the value from the row is assigned to `@var1`), or 2) a subquery isn't valid in that context.

---

EDIT

According the the MySQL Reference Manual 5.7

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

It looks like a subquery is supported in the context of a LOAD DATA statement.

Comment: Yes the manual shows that you can access the user variable. Using the @var1 results into null value being assigned to col1 and hence it fails. I need to set the value that is being read from the csv file.

Comment: Yes, I know you can assign a field to a user variable `@var1`, and reference the user variable in an expression on the right side of the `SET`. What I was questioning was *when* does that subquery get evaluated. I'm suspicious that the subquery gets evaluated once, *before* the outer LOAD DATA starts processing rows. The test I suggested in my answer was designed to check that. Before the LOAD DATA statement, set the variable to a value you expect to work, a value that causes the subquery `(select max(id) ...` to return a different result than the value of the field on the first row does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problems. Part of my problem was that, using your table definition as an example, T1.col1 is set to NOT NULL but the expression "select max(id) from T2 where col2 = @var1" resulted in nothing being returned and so MySQL attempted to assign a null value to col1. That didn't solve everything, but it was a start.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'streets.csv'
INTO TABLE streets
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(pre_dir, name, suffix, post_dir, @community, @state)
SET community_id       = (SELECT community_id FROM communities_v WHERE community_name = @community AND state_abbr = @state);
```

EDIT: I had originally put a bunch of other stuff here that I thought was related to the problem, but as it turns out, didn't. It really was a data problem. The subquery I'm using had certain combinations of @community and @state that had no value for community_id, so I would double-check your own subquery to see if it returns a value in all cases.